# Django looping through items not showing

Tags: django

Hi I am looping through items being passed through the context but nothing is showing.

This is the data I have:

```
{"error":[],"result":{"USDT":"60000.00000000","CHZ":"13773.0349000000","ZRX":"0.0000000000","ZUSD":"67787.8285","DOT":"0.0000000000","COMP":"0.0000034600","ENJ":"257.6815000000","ADA":"2473.80445621","XXDG":"17006.92601155","ALGO":"32063.69514500","XXBT":"0.0000012880","SUSHI":"172.4585500000","SOL":"1133.3543869800","DASH":"0.5104491200","LINK":"144.2407000000","ATOM":"151.26763831","XXLM":"6926.27220000","XXRP":"0.00000000","XETH":"14.5877343640","TRX":"923.80015900","KNC":"0.0000000000","BAL":"0.0000000000","XLTC":"11.4923900000","KSM":"24.7142610000","SC":"0.0000000200","OCEAN":"652.6077000000","MATIC":"1838.9295772000","AAVE":"83.6218990800","ZGBP":"30622.0790","XZEC":"0.0000073100"}}
```

It is passed in my context like this:

```
def kraken(request):
    """ A view to return kraken page """
    context = {
        'api_reply': api_reply,
    }
    return render(request, 'home/kraken.html', context)
```

And inside my template I have this:

```
{% for k, v in api_reply.items %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ k }}</td>
  <td>{{ v }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I have no errors showing but it is not displaying, any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are stored in the `result` subelement, you thus should enumerate over `api_reply.result.items`, not `api_reply.items`:

```
{% for k, v in api_reply.result.items %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ k }}</td>
  <td>{{ v }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore you need to convert the JSON blob into Python objects, for example with:

```
import json

def kraken(request):
    """ A view to return kraken page """
    context = {
        'api_reply': json.loads(api_reply),
    }
    return render(request, 'home/kraken.html', context)
```

Comment: Ah okay I see that, for some reason making that change nothing is showing, I know it is 100% passed through if I do {{ api_result }} it prints

Comment: @Jack_T: can you edit the question with the view where you pass the data to the context?

Comment: @Jack_T: did you use the `response`, or the `response.json()` of the API request? The former will return a string that contains the JSON blob whereas the latter will return a dictionary.

Comment: Ah I have it like this: api_reply_read = urllib2.urlopen(api_request).read() and then - api_reply = api_reply_read.decode()

Comment: @Jack_T: what if you use `import json`, and use `api_reply = json.loads(api_reply_read.decode())`?